# Omission of Non-Restrictive "Which Is"

Tags: non-restrictive

*Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart, was a prolific and influential composer of the Classical era.*

The above line is cited from the article on Mozart in Wikipedia.
As all English learners learned, the **non-restrictive** phrase "which is (was)" or "who is (was)" must be always left. In this line, however, it seems that "who was" is omitted before "baptised as ...", that is, I think it should be like this:

*Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, who was baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart, was a prolific and influential composer of the Classical era.*

Why the non-restrictive phrase is omitted?
I need justification for this matter. I'd be so happy if I could solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure your assertion about deletion in nonrestrictive phrases is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart* is a **non-finite relative clause**. As such, *which is* or *who is* has not been "omitted."

In the sentence you quote it is used  as a post-modifier.

It can also be  used as a pre-modifier, as in

> *Baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart*,  Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart...

Hopefully you can see  that *which is* or *who is* has not simply been "omitted" from the clause.

This is not the same thing as the **finite relative clause** *who was baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart*. It can be used only as a post-modifier.

Both types of clause  (non-finite and) finite can be used to add supplemental information.

See [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/clauses-finite-and-non-finite) and [Grammaring](http://www.grammaring.com/non-finite-relative-clauses).

Comment: I'm so grateful for your helpful answer as well as your kindness.
My question of that sentence appears to have been solved, and now, another arose: Why the commas have to be, at least in this case, put after the subject and before the verb respectively? Could I rewrite the line as below?
Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart was a prolific and influential composer of the Classical era.

Comment: As far as I know, a sentence that uses a post-modifier doesn't require any comma for it. For example, 
The device transmits a signal. The signal transmitted from the device is received at the receiver.
is a correct sentence that includes a post-modifier. However,
The device transmits a signal. The signal, transmitted from the device, is received at the receiver.
or
The device transmits a signal. Transmitted from the device, the signal is received at the receiver.
seem to be something wrong....

Comment: You can use commas if you want to add supplemental information (which, unfortunately,  is often called unessential information). So both *The signal transmitted from the device is received at the receiver* and *The signal, transmitted from the device,  is received at the receiver* are correct. Comma usage is the same as with the finite relative clause.

Comment: As a pre-modifier the comma is used, as illustrated in my answer. So *Transmitted from the device, the signal is received at the receiver* is correct.  I can't fathom not using a comma in *Baptised as Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart...*. Can you? We can't be sure  where the baptised name stops and the everyday name begins. Besides that it is way too much of a mouthful to say without pausing.

Comment: At this point, this comment thread has become a discussion, something which Stack Exchange does not like. So if you have additional questions, you should edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: It can't possibly be a non-finite relative clause, since non-finite relatives are always infinitivals. And because it's a supplement (notice the comma) it is not a modifier, since supplements by definition are non-restrictive (as the OP commented). It is in fact a supplementary non-finite clause, i.e. a separate unit of information, parenthetical or additional, adding non-essential information about the head, "Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart". It's the non-finite equivalent of a supplementary (non-restrictive) relative clause, though not itself a relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ I don’t subscribe to the same grammar as you do. Specifically, in the grammar I follow I disagree that all non-finite relative clauses are infinitival. So there’s not universality on the issue.

Comment: @BillJ I do want to apologize for my untoward remarks to you yesterday, I apologize.